# /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes not present in Fedora 33

Tags: fedora

I have an old script that do

`$(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes)`

In fedora 33 this file is not present.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing `/sys/fs/cgroup` was mounted as `cgroup2` amd `memory.limit_in_bytes` isn't available.  What does `findmnt /sys/fs/group` show?

Comment: Hi, findmnt /sys/fs/group shows nothing

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I had a typo.  What does `findmnt /sys/fs/cgroup` show?

Comment: findmnt /sys/fs/cgroup

TARGET         SOURCE  FSTYPE  OPTIONS
/sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to new cgroup v2.
To resolve this, revert cgroup to v1:

```
sudo sed -i '/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/ s/"$/ systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"/' /etc/default/grub
```

and reboot.

After this **/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes** will be present.

Comment: How did the original script use `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`?  I'm wondering if `cgroup2` has something that will suffice for the script.  I also wonder about changing the default mount params because of one script.  Might other problems arise because other system resources/functions/etc. may expect `cgroup2`?

Answer (score 0):

Before rebooting, it's necessary to redo the command to regenerate grub.
For Fedora 33, the commands are:

### BIOS

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

### UEFI

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```